# JQuery select tabs anchor attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

While migrating from jQuery 1.7 to 1.9 one of our function has stopped working. We were using the following code to get value of the currently selected tab's anchor.

```
select:function(event,ui)
{  
    var messageId=$(ui.tab).attr('data-message_id');
```

I have tried migrating to the new activate event, but cannot seem to get a handle to the anchor tag and it's attribute. What would be the best way to do so?

```
    activate:function(event,ui)
        {
            console.log(($(ui.newTab.children()[0]).prop('data-message_id')));
            var messageId=$(ui.newTab > a).prop('data-message_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give `ui.newTab.children()[0]` it returns the `DOMElement` and not the jQuery element. So you need to use `.get(0)` instead:

```
ui.newTab.children().get(0)
```

Then you can use the jQuery's methods... `:)`

Comment: ncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).attr is not a function .. is the error I get.  This works $(ui.newTab.children()[0]).attr('data-message_id'); but I don't think this is the right way to do this.

Comment: Cool.. what I am not able to understand is why attr or prop doesn't work. When I do a console.log() of the object it display the complete object to me, but the functions don't work.